# Not getting any highlights from ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to create a query that will return me a highlighted response. The query I have is:

```
POST myindex/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 1,
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "search for this"
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "pre_tags": [
      "<b>"
    ],
    "post_tags": [
      "</b>"
    ],
    "fields": {
      "_all": {}
    }
}}
```

But the result won't have any highlights, all it contain is the hits like this:

```
{
   "took": 0,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 0.2791085,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "devintranett_1",
            "_type": "searchdocuments",
            "_id": "/link/ae0089b649e14de080fd94acb79bdfcd.aspx?id=1412&epslanguage=no",
            "_score": 0.2791085,
            "_source": {
               "id": "/link/ae0089b649e14de080fd94acb79bdfcd.aspx?id=1412&epslanguage=no",
               "contentType": 0,
               "location": "/link/ae0089b649e14de080fd94acb79bdfcd.aspx?id=1412&epslanguage=no",
               "ingress": "...",
               "content": "...",
               "title": "...",
               "createdDate": "2014-01-15T15:16:24",
               "changedDate": "2014-01-15T15:16:45.887"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

What am I missing to get the highlighted results back?

**UPDATE:**

I think I figured it out, to get the highlights I need to have a match query, is that correct?

Comment: the query you use doesn't make a big difference here, have a look at my answer, and do let me know if it's clear or whether you have any further question...

Answer (score 0):

You chose the wrong field to highlight. In fact, highlighting means that the field needs to be indexed, so that its tokens can be retrieved (together with their positions and offsets). Also, the field needs to be stored in order to be highlighted and returned.

You don't usually need to store your fields separately as elasticsearch always stores the [`_source`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-source-field.html) field by default. The problem is that you chose to highlight the [`_all`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html) field, which is not part of your documents, thus not part of the `_source` field either. It would need to be stored separately in lucene, but it isn't by default.

I would suggest to switch to make highlighting on fields that actually appear in your documents. In fact, given that the `_all` field contains the content coming from all fields in your documents, its content might not be that nice to be shown to your users. As an experiment you can configure the `_all` field to be stored in lucene by changing the mappings for it to `"store":"yes"`. Just keep in mind that this would cause wasting some disk space too.